# Responsive web page not showing form data

Tags: php, forms, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive webpage that uses forms - I have used a select box

The result of selecting an item in the form's select box is showing on my desktop screen but when I use Chrome Web Developer Tools - View Responsive Layouts
the result of the selected item is not shown.

```
 <!--testX.php-->
<form action="add_to_bookAroom.php" method="POST" class="booking_form" autocomplete="off">
<select name="guests1" id="guests1">
<option value=' '>Rooms & Guests</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
</select>
<button>View Rates</button>
</form>

 <!-- add_to_bookAroom.php -->
<?php
$num_guests = $_POST['guests1'];  
echo $num_guests;
echo "<br>";
echo "FRED";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the form and checking the styles and see what css attribute might be affecting the visibility of your form?

Comment: Yes...still not working,,,

Comment: The problem is that i was switching between desktop and responsive...ie selecting the item in desktop and then reviewing the result in responsive. if i select the item in responsive and review the result / page in responsive then the result is OK.